# Would a two word domain name with a shared letter between the words be treated the same for SEO as the fuller name?

Tags: seo, domains

I found a domain name (2 words) that is not available.  Then I found almost the same domain name with a slight difference, the last letter of the first word is the same of the first letter of the second word.

```
Ex : jamessecret.com (not available)
     jamesecret.com (available)
```

In terms of SEO, is it seen as the same to Google? Would search engines interpret them the same?